# WebPartPages:AllowFraming Only works once then it trows a X-Frame-Options error

Tags: 2013, iframe, x-frame

I have a ASPX page and i really would like to load it in a iframe. It is a simple overview page.

i added the following syntax:

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />
```

It works only once. If i load the page for the first time the page is loaded correctly. But when i reload the page F5. Then it throws the error:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options:  does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

If i empty the cookies then it works again or when i restart the iis server.

I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: what technologies/IE browser modes are you using on the main and the iframed pages? also, check for javascript errors on the console.